# php regex validate birthdate

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Im having difficulties figuring out how to do the following `preg_match` in php.
I have a HTML form where the user can enter his or hers birthdate by day, month & year.

How do i validate the following
Day: make sure it's a number between 1 and 31, actually between 01 and 31
Month: make sure it's a number between 1 and 12, actually between 01 and 12
Year: make sure it's a number between 1800 and 2012, actually between 1800 and 2012

```
if (preg_match( ????? )) {
     echo " SUCCESS";
} else { 
     echo " ERROR";
}
```

Thanks...

Comment: There's no need to use a regex - http://php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php

Comment: [`php + validate + date`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+validate+date)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkdate needs 3 different parameters, for validating one input with preg_match, use pattern:

```
(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.]((?|19|20)\d\d)
```

it validates correct date in style dd-mm-yyy and dd.mm.yyyy and dd/mm/yyyy and if you want, it also parses values out for each parameter

Comment: One downside to using a regex is that it will validate a date like '31/02/2012'

Comment: Then you can use preg_match results in combination with checkdate() function

Comment: Thanks Alvar could you please explain what the 3 different combinations means?

Answer (score 1):

you can do this by [`checkdate()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php) function